# select jquery присваивание класса

Tags: jquery

Как провести вот эту манипуляцию с select?

```
$(function() {
    $("#a").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("ase");
    });
});
```

Имеется `select`:

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

В зависимости от выбранного присваивать к `<div id="a"></div>` определенный класс.

Например, имеется вот такой вот `select`:

```
<select>
    <option value="one">Одна колонка</option>
    <option value="two">Две колонки</option>
    <option value="table">Таблицей</option>
<select>
```

и имеется класс контейнера `<div class="container"></div>` Как при выборе определенного `option`-а мне манипулировать с контейнером, к примеру выбрал одну колонку присвоился класс `column`, выбрал две колонки этот класс удалился.

Всем спасибо

Comment: Каков алгоритм преобразования значения селекта в имя класса?

Comment: К примеру выбрал 1, к #a присваивается класс 1 и так далее

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ на вопрос, отметьте его как "верный".

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте так:

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $('#container').removeClass('one two table').addClass($(this).val());
});
```

```css
/* CSS только чтобы был виден установленный класс */
.one:after { content: " class=one" }
.two:after { content: " class=two" }
.table:after { content: " class=table" }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">div</div> 
<select>
  <option value="one">Одна колонка</option>
  <option value="two">Две колонки</option>
  <option value="table">Таблицей</option>
<select>
```

Comment: А есть какие-нибудь объективные причины использовать `$('select').prop('value')` вместо `$('select').val()`?

Comment: если бы название свойства было бы не value :)

Comment: На мой взгляд, использование `$('select').val()` предпочтительнее из за общего интерфейса работы со всеми инпутами. `$('select').prop('value')` попахивает магией и, раз нет объективных причин его использовать, лучше от него отказаться ;)